# Error summing an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, sum

So I'm new to ruby, I was practicing doing hackerrank excercices and when I had to sum an array I got the following error:

> solution.rb:6:in +': nil can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)
>         from solution.rb:6:inblock in simpleArraySum' from solution.rb:5:in each'
>         from solution.rb:5:insimpleArraySum' from solution.rb:15:in `'

Code:

```
def sum(n, arr)
    sum = 0
    for i in (0..n) do
        sum += arr[i]
    end
    return sum
end
```

Similar js code:

```
const sum = function (n, arr) {
    let sum = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
};
```

Comment: The short way is `def my_sum(arr); arr.sum; end`. [Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) made its debut in Ruby v2.4. To support earlier versions of Ruby you can write `def my_sum; arr.reduce { |t,n| t+n }; end`, or simply `def my_sum(arr); arr.reduce(:+); end`. See [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`). You don't need the size of the array as an argument since that can be computed within the method. Best not to give names to your methods or variables that are names of Ruby's built-in methods.

Comment: The issue is with upper bound(i == n). You should use ruby style of coding in ruby. Look at methods like `inject`, `map`, `each` in Array to solve it.

Comment: As already mentioned it's an upper bound issue, you may have been caught by the 2 dot vs. 3 dot range issue `(0...9).map(&:itself)` vs `(0..9).map(&:itself)` (the first **does not** include 9, the second **does** include 9). If you had seen it done elsewhere this way and are wondering why it worked there and not here...but as mentioned, there are better ways to sum an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your n is bigger than the number of elements in your array-1 so it tries to sum a nil.

Here a better way to do this in Ruby, with an each in stead of a for which is seldom used. If you want to use a for, you could get the length of the array from arr.length instead of the parameter n.

```
def sum arr
  sum = 0
  arr.each do |e|
    sum += e
  end
  sum
end
```

The real Ruby way would be the following.
You inject a variable filled with 0 and enumerate each element of the array.
The variables between the || are this variable, used to remember our sum and the element that is being enumerated.

```
[1,5].inject(0){|sum, e| sum + e } 
=>6
```

or shorter

```
[1,5].inject(0, &:+) 
=>6
```

or still better/shorter/readable (thus Ruby like) if you use Ruby 2.4

```
[1, 5].sum
=> 6
```

Comment: No need for the &: `[1, 5].reduce(0, :+)`. Also if you don't care if the empty array returns `nil` then you can also skip the 0: `[1, 5].reduce(:+)`

Comment: in that case my mistake was using `(0..n)` it was including the n value. Shoud've used `(0...n)` instead. Also, all your options worked, thanks. Also, i had to use that `n` because of the exercice, otherwise I'd have used length too. Thank u so much!

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the addition operation is unsuccessful because one or more of the values is nil.

In this case, are you sure that when `i==n` there will be a value at `i[n]`?

Remember, arrays are 0-indexed. Meaning, if the length of the array is n, the index of the nth value will actually be n-1.

So when your loop hits `n`, you end up trying to evaluate `sum += nil`, which produces the error you are seeing.

Comment: To be more precise, for any array `arr`, `arr[n]` returns `nil` if `n >= arr.size`.

Comment: for what i've studied about arrays in ruby so far if i use 0..n with two dots it won't include the n value, and with 0...n it includes. So in this case it shouldn't be considering the n value correct?

Comment: (0..n) is inclusive of n

Comment: true, it's the opposite, two dots includes and three dows not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the best practice here is probably to just use the arr#each enumerable method (q.v.)

That aside: I'm not sure what your variable n is supposed to be, but I'm guessing it's the number of elements in your array. I'd offer that it's better practice to use the arr#length method (which returns the *number* of elements in the array; subtracting 1 syncs the loop with a zero-indexed array.)

```
test_arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

def sum(arr)
    sum = 0
    for i in (0..arr.length-1) do
        sum += arr[i]
    end
    return sum
end

sum(test_arr) => 15
```

(FYI: Using arr.length is probably better practice in JavaScript as well (although using the JS .forEach or .reduce callback functions might be even better.))

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length -1; i++) {
```